# Gallery of images with long descriptions in Joomla

Tags: joomla, gallery, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I need to make something like gallery of magazine covers in joomla, and after clicking one image, it should open a page, where viewer would see an image of cover (that he could open in full size) and table of contents with links to some articles. Administrator should also be able to (reasonably) easily add a new covers with content to a gallery. I'm more like a Drupal guy, so I'm asking Joomla guys - what would be the best/easiest way to achieve this (including using extensions etc)? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that within the standard Joomla framework. In this case -

1. Have a main category that each issue would be a subcategory of.
2. Each issue of the magazine would be a new category, the magazine cover would be the image for that category.
3. Add the content as articles in the appropriate category
4. Display the parent category to get the listing of each issue.
5. Clicking the category would then display a list of links to the articles within the category.

This can definitely be accomplished with the K2 extension, but you can probably do it within the Joomla category/article framework with some simple template overrides.

Answer (score 0):

To suit your needs, you will be best off using a [Photo Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery) component and changing the link from opening an iframe/full size image, to an article OR a [Portfolio](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/portfolio) component which I think might be the easier option.

One of my personal favorites is [BT Content Slider](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase/19125). I have used it on multiple pages and adapted the code to suit our own needs and it works like a charm. Would also recommend it for you too.